# Allowing implicit conversion for a single value

Tags: c++

I have a `Flags` class that behaves similarly to `std::bitset` that is replacing bitpacked integers in an older codebase.  To enforce compliance with the newer class, I want to disallow implicit conversion from `int` types.

```
enum class Flag : unsigned int {
  none = 0,
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 4,
  //...
};

class Flags {
public:
  Flags();
  Flags(const Flag& f);
  explicit Flags(unsigned int); // don't allow implicit
  Flags(const Flags&);

private:
  unsigned int value;
};
```

I would like to allow implicit construction and assignment only from the `Flag` and `Flags` types.  However, I would still like some function calls that take a `Flags` parameter to accept a literal `0`, but not other integers:

```
void foo(const Flags& f);

foo(Flags(0)); // ok but ugly
foo(1); // illegal because of explicit constructor
foo(0); // illegal, but I want to allow this
```

Is this possible?  To allow `0` to be implicitly converted while disallowing other values?

Comment: Why is `0` special here?

Comment: You could add a constructor taking void*, which will be invoked with 0. Then assert the pointer is null in the ctor. Thats the first thing that comes to mind, maybe theres a cleaner way. Literal 1 will not convert implicitly to void *

Comment: @tadman In function calls that take a bitpacked integer, it passes no bits.  In my codebase there are a lot of function calls where a bit vector holds optional parameters, and many times the call is made with a literal 0.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Dude, make that an answer so I can accept it.  Works beautifully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach:

Add a constructor which takes `void*`.

Since literal `0` is implicitly convertible to a `void*` null pointer, and literal `1` isn`t, this will give the desired behavior indicated. For safety you can assert that the pointer is null in the ctor.

A drawback is that now your class is constructible from anything implicitly convertible to `void *`. Some unexpected things are so convertible -- for instance prior to C++11, `std::stringstream` was convertible to `void*`, basically as a hack because `explicit operator bool` did not exist yet.

But, this may work out fine in your project as long as you are aware of the potential pitfalls.

Edit:

Actually, I remembered a way to make this safer. Instead of `void*` use a pointer to a private type.

It might look like this:

```
class Flags {
private:
  struct dummy {};
public:
  Flags (dummy* d) { ... }
  ...
};
```

The literal `0` conversion will still work, and it's significantly harder for some user-defined type to accidentally convert to `Flags::dummy *` unintentionally.